# update table using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Update

the purpose of this excerise is to eliminate passing the `@RegModifiedDateTime`   again what i want is i should be able to read `ModifiedDateTime` by passing `Id`

example: if i pass Id = `564` then i should be able to read

```
`schoold_Id and ModifiedDateTime`
```

**end update**

here is how my table looks like for SchoolRegistration:

```
school_id       id     active        modifydatetime
--------------------------------------------------
432        564       1               2008-12-14 13:15:38.750
342        564       1              2008-12-14 14:15:50.470
353        564       1              2008-12-14 14:19:46.703
```

**end update**

how do i loop to update my SchoolRegistration table? the id might have 1 or many rows in the SchoolRegistration but the thing is that `RegModifiedDateTime` is a unique for concurrency purpose and i should loop to get the right modifydatetime for that id.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[del_schoolRegistration]
    @Id bigint, 
    @RegModifiedDateTime datetime
as
begin  
    declare @rowsAffected int
    begin tran 


        --registration
        update SchoolRegistration
                   set Active = 0,
                    ModifiedDateTime = getdate()            
        where (Id = @Id and RegModifiedDateTime = @RegModifiedDateTime or @RegModifiedDateTime is null )


    if (@rowsAffected < 1) begin
        rollback tran
    end
    else begin
        commit tran
    end

    return @rowsAffected

end
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this `UPDATE` on a `CURSOR`?, can't you just do one `UPDATE`?. also, I believe that your condition `OR @RegModifiedDateTime is null` is wrong, since its gonna update your whole table when that column is null, instead of just for that `@id`

Comment: RegModifiedDateTime is a unique for concurrency purpose and it should loop to get the right modifydatetime for that id.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah "is unique for concurrency purpose" you're going to have to explain that bit. Also the resolution on getdate() is going to cause you problems

Comment: @Abu Hamzah I think that I don't understand over what variable or value you want to loop your cursor....if you need to go through all possible datetimes until you find the right one, then you are in big trouble, since it can take a very very long time

Comment: @conrad: i update my question see how my tbl structure/data

Comment: Do you mean you only want to update the last record for the Id?

Comment: @Lamak: see my updated question may be you will understand what exactly i am trying to do

Comment: @cyberkiwi: i want to update `modifydatetime ` based on the id and if you see the `modifydatetime ` is a unique

Comment: @Abu. What I don't get is what kind of system requires a modifydatetime  field that has a Unique constraint.

Comment: @Conrad: its for `Optimistic Concurrency` Database Updating

Comment: @Abu Hamzah Optimistic Concurrency doesn't require this. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Question is unclear. Stored Proc refers to both ModifiedDateTime and **Reg**ModifiedDateTime. Sample data does not have the second column at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i endup using curor:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
DECLARE @ProductID INT
DECLARE @getProductID CURSOR
SET @getProductID = CURSOR FOR
SELECT ProductID
FROM Production.Product
OPEN @getProductID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getProductID INTO @ProductID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @ProductID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getProductID INTO @ProductID
END
CLOSE @getProductID
DEALLOCATE @getProductID
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   --registration
    ;with tmp as (
        select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by RegModifiedDateTime desc)
        from SchoolRegistration
        where (Id = @Id and RegModifiedDateTime = @RegModifiedDateTime or @RegModifiedDateTime is null ))
    update tmp
               set Active = 0,
                ModifiedDateTime = getdate()            
    WHERE rn=1
```

What happens here is that if you did not know the RegModifiedDateTime you are looking for (by passing @RegModifiedDateTime as NULL), the query will catch them all for the ID due to `@RegModifiedDateTime is null`, but update ONLY the LATEST RegModifiedDateTime based on the row_numbering and CTE table definition.

#### EDIT

The above query retains the option to pass in a direct @RegModifiedDateTime should a record other than the latest need updating.  To always update only the latest, drop the WHERE filter against @RegModifiedDateTime completely

```
   --registration
    ;with tmp as (
        select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by RegModifiedDateTime desc)
        from SchoolRegistration
        where Id = @Id)
    update tmp
               set Active = 0,
                ModifiedDateTime = getdate()            
    WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: @CyberKiwi: the purpose of this excerise is to eliminate passing the `@RegModifiedDateTime` i dont see any benefit using the above code... again what i want is i should be able to read `RegModifiedDateTime ` by passing `Id`, for an example: if i pass Id = 564 the ni should be able to read `schoold_Id and ModifiedDateTime`

Comment: @cyberkiwi unless I completely misunderstood, the OP is looking for a solution that results in generating unique ModidifedDateTimes for each record

Comment: @Conrad Frix I tried, but I failed to understand what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: when i execute jsut this code `;with tmp as (         select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by RegModifiedDateTime desc)         from SchoolRegistration         where Id = @Id) ` i get this error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @abu, you `cannot` run that alone. WITH sets up a Common Table Expression that you need to do something with, like the UPDATE statement following it

Comment: cyberwiki: okay but one think you missing is passing `where Id = @Id and RegModifiedDateTime = reading through loop may be???`